# how export .csv file for Natural Language Classifier (NLC) Watson service?

Tags: ibm-watson, nl-classifier

There is a Rest Api for the service Natural Language Classifier (NLC) of Watson to export the file .csv to train ?

Answer (score 0):

The API doesn't allow you to retrieve the training data.

See the Natural Language Classifier API: https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/apis/natural-language-classifier-v1